# Count occurence of unique value in 2nd field using awk

Tags: unix, awk

I'm using this syntax to count occurrence of unique values in 2nd field of the file. Can somebody explain how does this work. How is Unix calculating this count ? Is it reading each line or whole file as one.. how is it assigning count and incrementing it?

Command:

```
awk -F:  '{a[$2]++} END {for ( i in a) { print i,a[i]}}' inputfile
```

Comment: this is in fact counting how many times each 2nd field occurs.

Answer (score 2):

It's not *Unix calculating* but awk; awk is not Unix or shell, it's a language. Presented awk program calculates how many times each unique value in the second field (`$2`. separated by `:`) occurs and outputs the values and related counts.

```
awk -F: '              # set the field separator to ":"
{                      
                       # awk reads in records or lines in a loop
    a[$2]++            # here it hashes each value to a and counts each occurrance 
} 
END {                  # after all records have been processed
    for ( i in a) {    # hash a is looped thru in no particular order
        print i,a[i]   # and value-count pairs are outputed
    }
}' inputfile
```

If you want to learn more about awk, please read following quote (* see below) by @EdMorton: *The best source of all awk information is the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. If you have any other book, throw it away, and if you're trying to learn from a web site - don't as most of them are full of complete nonsense. Just get the book.*

*) Now go read the book.

**Edit** How `a[$2]++` works:

Sample data and `a[$2]`'s value:

```
1 val1 # a[$2]++ causes: a["val1"] = 1
2 val2 # a[$2]++ causes: a["val2"] = 1
3 val1 # a[$2]++ causes: a["val1"] = 2
4 val1 # a[$2]++ causes: a["val1"] = 3
```

Comment: Thank you James. I want to understand how a[$2] ++ is working. can you please elaborate "# here it hashes each value to a and counts each occurrance" .

Comment: Thank you James. Yes its adequate and helpful.